# I want to concatenate two tables. Table A(a, b, c), Table B(d) should become Table A (a,b,c, d)

Tags: mysql

I want to append a table with another table. Table A(a, b, c), Table B(d) should become Table A(a,b,c, d). Assume both tables have same number of records.

Comment: How do you want to "concatenate" them?  How do you know which row(s) go where?

Comment: There are no conditions. I just want to append them. Is that possible?

Comment: How do you want to append them?  Do you want them to be in the same *order* or do you want to just randomly stick values wherever?  You need some sort of condition for this to make sense.  Hint: Use a `JOIN`.

Comment: Wait, do you want to `SELECT` this result or do you want to update the table in the database?  If you want to update, first you'll need to `ALTER TABLE tableA` to add the 4th column, then you'll need to `INSERT` values for each row.

Comment: I am trying to extract a substring from the field of a table and put it as a new field into the table. example: "[25550] keep me posted" I am extracting value in bracket which is 25550 and trying to put into a newly created column.

Comment: Add (by using [edit]) some sample data and the desired result to your question.

Answer (score 0):

I do not think there is any way to do this. Also, this is not logical. What you can do is do a join between the tables. A join is necessarily a [Cross product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartesian_product) between table A and table B. Read more about [joins](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/33052/Visual-Representation-of-SQL-Joins).